# Removing internal braces from a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation

I have

```
{{{{2/3, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, Sqrt[2]/3}, {0, 0}}}, {{{0, 0}, {Sqrt[2]/3,
 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 1/3}}}}
```

I need

```
{{2/3, 0, 0, Sqrt[2]/3}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {Sqrt[2]/3, 0, 0, 1/3}}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 11):

[`ArrayFlatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html) will do the job:

```
ArrayFlatten[
 {
  {
   {{2/3, 0}, {0, 0}},
   {{0, Sqrt[2]/3}, {0, 0}}
  },
  {
   {{0, 0}, {Sqrt[2]/3, 0}},
   {{0, 0}, {0, 1/3}}
  }
 }
]

(* Out:
{{2/3, 0, 0, Sqrt[2]/3}, 
 {0, 0, 0, 0}, 
 {0, 0, 0, 0}, 
 {Sqrt[2]/3, 0, 0, 1/3}}
*)
```

Answer (score 3):

`ArrayFlatten[]` is of course the best solution here; nevertheless, one can also use `Flatten[]` with an appropriate second argument:

```
Flatten[{{{{2/3, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, Sqrt[2]/3}, {0, 0}}},
         {{{0, 0}, {Sqrt[2]/3, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 1/3}}}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}]
   {{2/3, 0, 0, Sqrt[2]/3}, {0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0}, {Sqrt[2]/3, 0, 0, 1/3}}
```